# Google pay and Credit card in the mobile app

Tags: buttons, layout, mobile-application, payment

I just need one or two advice, regarding on this new booking system as the developer team create it without my knowledge and didn't ask me for advice or design UX before they went developed it and it on staging app and now they are not sure

the current one

[image]

We use when the custom book it through "request booking" and the message alert box will appear on it. we are using Stripe Credit card for lat 2-3 years.

At the moment, clients want google pay and apple pay on it. but Developer team or leader didn't inform me, and they went ahead to add google pay/ Apple pay.

The new function is when they click request booking button as same as before but alert message is removed and the next function is showing two button (google pay and Credit card) as customers can have two choice.

Now they ask me for advice (as it already developed) they are not sure with the word "Saved Credit Card" they ask me what is correct word.

[image]

the advice I'm asking you, I don't like it. what should i said

Comment: "Saved Credit Card" implies that the user cannot add a new credit card through this payment system, is that correct?

Comment: the "saved Credit Card" is bad idea, they just create as it go along, the user have credit card details in the profile.

Answer (score 1):

If you are offering Google Pay and Apple Pay options, shouldn't the icon and text reflect those choices?

From both a visual design perspective and also in terms of the consistency in labels for the buttons, I suggest that there are some arguments for updates that will allow for a better user experience.

If you are developing a style guide or design system, it would also be good for developers to be familiar with the conventions in case they want to deviate from it for a particular reason.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I am afraid the ship has sailed. What you mention is what I did, I told them as they need to go design guide also they need to reach out to me or UX team first before the Developer team decided, and we agree on what the client need or their user experience, not developer team

Comment: @StevenSmith so since this question was asked 8 months ago, what changes resulted in your actions and has the process for making design changes improved?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the delay, The function is better and improved, as App ->setting -> payment -> "pay by a card" or "google pay /apple pay" then click on prefer payment. so the user can pick which one. When they make a booking and the status said "Pay now" as one button. it been working ever since. but we still do research and find improvment and better